# Can't boot into Windows after aborted install

Tags: kubuntu, uefi, windows-10, ideapad

I got a new Lenovo Y700 Ideapad which came with Windows 10. I booted Kubuntu 15.10 and was in the process of manually organizing the partitions. I decided to abort the installation.

After clicking back a few times I got a pop-up window asking me something about UEFI boot mode. I can't recall exactly what it was because I didn't pay attention to it. I didn't think it was going to change my bootloader or anything because I was clicking back in order to get to the window where you can choose Try/Install Kubuntu.

Anyway, now my computer doesn't boot into Windows anymore. If the USB stick is plugged in, it boots Kubuntu. Otherwise, it tries to do a network boot.

Question: How do I revert what Kubuntu changed (make Windows boot again)?

EDIT 1:

Found the pop-up. I clicked 'Go back'.

[image]

Comment: When you don't want to have Ubuntu (and its boot loader GRUB) installed, you must reinstall/restore Windows' boot loader. In that case, it's no Ubuntu question but a Windows question and must be asked on [su] instead of here. Else please clarify.

Comment: It is an Ubuntu question because the Ubuntu installer caused the issue. I wanted to understand what happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading Windows 10 from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO). I burned the ISO onto a USB stick with Rufus and booted it by repeatedly pressing F12. I tried to save the Windows installation using the automated recovery tools but it didn't work. The original install couldn't be detected. It might've been possible to recover it with further efforts but I chose not to waste time.

Fortunately, the recovery tools allow you to modify the UEFI settings so I managed to disable UEFI and switch back to good ol' BIOS to prevent further dual-booting issues. Thereafter, I reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

A computer that came with Windows 10 almost certainly boots in EFI/UEFI mode, so the message claiming that the computer is booting in BIOS mode is highly suspect. It could be that the computer really *is* booting in BIOS mode (say, if you re-installed Windows yourself); but it's more likely that something is causing the Ubuntu installer to be confused. This could be related to your boot problem, in fact -- it could be that your disk is failing and returning garbage instead of good data on some critical sectors, for instance. OTOH, it sounds like you got the warning message only *after* you aborted the installation, which suggests it could be a false alarm caused by a bug in the installer. This is all highly speculative, though.

Unless you passed the point where the installer actually resized partitions (when you click past the screen on which you can resize partitions), it should not have written anything to the disk. If you did click past that point, then any answer to your question depends on what you did to those partitions, and you've provided no information on that. For instance, if you deleted or created a fresh filesystem on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) you would have destroyed the Windows boot loader. If you resized the ESP, you might have damaged (but perhaps not destroyed) its boot loader. In either case, a fix in Windows is appropriate, and you should ask about the situation on a Windows forum. In fact, I'd say this is the way to go unless you finished with an Ubuntu installation; without Ubuntu more-or-less fully installed on the computer, any potential Ubuntu-based solution is likely to fail.

One possible source of problems is the Windows Fast Startup feature, which turns shutdown operations into suspend-to-disk operations. This is extremely bad for dual-boot configurations because it leads to disk corruption on shared partitions, including the ESP. If you didn't disable this feature, then it could be that accessing the ESP from the Ubuntu installer caused disk corruption -- especially if you resized the ESP. Before you make another attempt, you should [disable this feature,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) along with the related [Hibernate feature.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. There's a problem with the installer most likely. The computer is brand new. Windows 10 came with it. Indeed, Fast Startup was enabled by default which may have played a role.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.

Comment: Interesting. I wish I had known earlier about it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your system and in terminal run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Share the result here. in case it cannot solve the problem, this output can help to find the problem

Comment: I haven't actually installed Ubuntu. I aborted.

Comment: You can do it from USB also